# Is it possible to get the final name of a dependency via Mavens properties?

Tags: maven-2, maven-3

It's possible to get the final name of the current project.

```
${project.build.finalName}
```

Is this also possible for dependencies? I'm searching for something like this:

```
${project.build.dependencies.0.finalName}
```

Based on this example pom dependency cutout.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.stackoverflow</groupId>
  <artifactId>stackoverflow-question</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

The final name will likely be stackoverflow-question-1.6.0-SNAPSHOT, but as this may be variable due to locked snapshots or releases, I wan't to read it dynamically. Can you help me with that? Thank you very much.

Comment: You can probably read it from the artifact manifest with ant or groovie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all, I found it by myself hidden in [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580562/maven-antrun-and-dependencies) question.

```
<property name="log4j" value="${maven.dependency.log4j.log4j.jar.path}"/>
<echo message="${log4j}"/>
```

Comment: Note that this is using the `maven-antrun-plugin` and doesn't straight in the maven pom.

Comment: Would you please put all the tags we should put inside the pom to see the output?