# Referencing the Maven dependencies in antrun plugin

Tags: maven, maven-antrun-plugin

I want to refer maven project dependency in antrun plugin. I need to delete all libs that are present in WEB-INF/lib folder after maven assembling war process and to place there another dependenies. I found an article [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/examples/classpaths.html), but the example shown there doesn't work. Are there any other posibilities to do such stuff.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more what you like to achieve and why? It sounds weird.

Comment: I want to know if there is a posibility to access maven dependency from antrun plugin. I don't want to specify absolute path to libs. A sample use case: from antrun plugin copy some maven compile time dependency to some place

Comment: For such purpose you better use the maven-dependency-plugin which can handle this.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer individual dependencies in antrun plugin as, for example, `${junit:junit}`. See: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/examples/classpaths.html

See also: [Maven Antrun and Dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580562)